# Using GWT MVP on a single screen application

Tags: gwt, mvp

I apologize in advance as this is one of those "how does this work" type questions. I am a newbie to GWT MVP and I am trying to create a project similar to this one here:

[image: http://smist08.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/layout1.png]

where basically I have a menu of widgets/components that I can drag and drop onto a panel and doing so changes the properties shown in the Property disclosurepanel.

I have been reading about the official GWT MVP framework and they its described it seems like it expects each application state to represented by a whole new page (a View with an associated Place).

I am confused as to how this would work this type of application. That is, an application that has 1 basic screen that never entirely changes (i.e. user never navigates to a whole new screen) with sections that need to communicate to each other (i.e. dropping a widget loads a different set of properties).

I am sure I am misunderstanding something about MVP so if someone can just offer some advice on how to wrap my brain around this that would be great.

Comment: MVP is way overrated, it is proposed as a technique for "large scale applications" it is a tremenodous amoutn of boilerplate and too many levels of indirection for anything but the grandest applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not impossible to utilize the MVP paradigm with more than one on-screen regions.
You can read about a possible solution [in this article](http://tbroyer.posterous.com/gwt-21-activities-nesting-yagni). It's the last post of a four-part series. I suggest reading also the preceeding posts from the author with the same tags.

Comment: This along with another project I found here (http://95.110.143.4/layoutmvp/layoutmvp.html) helped explain how this can be done.  It took me a couple of days to get my own project working though as I mistakenly used RootPanel instead of RootLayoutPanel (not really related to MVP but a nasty gotcha if you are new to this GWT). 

One other thing I noticed is that you need to implement your own special ActivityMappers so that you can have a section that triggers an event on another without stopping it's own Activity.